# Why some menu item in the toolbar appears in a different colour?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar, android-color

I have three items in the toolbar menu in my app like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_vector_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/my_search_bar"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search2"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_reach_us"
        android:title="@string/action_help"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

This is what it looks like in the preview.

[image]

Following is the vector for android:icon="@drawable/ic_vector_settings"

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="512"
    android:viewportHeight="512">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="m272.066,512h-32.133c-25.989,0 -47.134,-21.144 -47.134,-47.133v-10.871c-11.049,-3.53 -21.784,-7.986 -32.097,-13.323l-7.704,7.704c-18.659,18.682 -48.548,18.134 -66.665,-0.007l-22.711,-22.71c-18.149,-18.129 -18.671,-48.008 0.006,-66.665l7.698,-7.698c-5.337,-10.313 -9.792,-21.046 -13.323,-32.097h-10.87c-25.988,0 -47.133,-21.144 -47.133,-47.133v-32.134c0,-25.989 21.145,-47.133 47.134,-47.133h10.87c3.531,-11.05 7.986,-21.784 13.323,-32.097l-7.704,-7.703c-18.666,-18.646 -18.151,-48.528 0.006,-66.665l22.713,-22.712c18.159,-18.184 48.041,-18.638 66.664,0.006l7.697,7.697c10.313,-5.336 21.048,-9.792 32.097,-13.323v-10.87c0,-25.989 21.144,-47.133 47.134,-47.133h32.133c25.989,0 47.133,21.144 47.133,47.133v10.871c11.049,3.53 21.784,7.986 32.097,13.323l7.704,-7.704c18.659,-18.682 48.548,-18.134 66.665,0.007l22.711,22.71c18.149,18.129 18.671,48.008 -0.006,66.665l-7.698,7.698c5.337,10.313 9.792,21.046 13.323,32.097h10.87c25.989,0 47.134,21.144 47.134,47.133v32.134c0,25.989 -21.145,47.133 -47.134,47.133h-10.87c-3.531,11.05 -7.986,21.784 -13.323,32.097l7.704,7.704c18.666,18.646 18.151,48.528 -0.006,66.665l-22.713,22.712c-18.159,18.184 -48.041,18.638 -66.664,-0.006l-7.697,-7.697c-10.313,5.336 -21.048,9.792 -32.097,13.323v10.871c0,25.987 -21.144,47.131 -47.134,47.131zM165.717,409.17c14.327,8.473 29.747,14.874 45.831,19.025 6.624,1.709 11.252,7.683 11.252,14.524v22.148c0,9.447 7.687,17.133 17.134,17.133h32.133c9.447,0 17.134,-7.686 17.134,-17.133v-22.148c0,-6.841 4.628,-12.815 11.252,-14.524 16.084,-4.151 31.504,-10.552 45.831,-19.025 5.895,-3.486 13.4,-2.538 18.243,2.305l15.688,15.689c6.764,6.772 17.626,6.615 24.224,0.007l22.727,-22.726c6.582,-6.574 6.802,-17.438 0.006,-24.225l-15.695,-15.695c-4.842,-4.842 -5.79,-12.348 -2.305,-18.242 8.473,-14.326 14.873,-29.746 19.024,-45.831 1.71,-6.624 7.684,-11.251 14.524,-11.251h22.147c9.447,0 17.134,-7.686 17.134,-17.133v-32.134c0,-9.447 -7.687,-17.133 -17.134,-17.133h-22.147c-6.841,0 -12.814,-4.628 -14.524,-11.251 -4.151,-16.085 -10.552,-31.505 -19.024,-45.831 -3.485,-5.894 -2.537,-13.4 2.305,-18.242l15.689,-15.689c6.782,-6.774 6.605,-17.634 0.006,-24.225l-22.725,-22.725c-6.587,-6.596 -17.451,-6.789 -24.225,-0.006l-15.694,15.695c-4.842,4.843 -12.35,5.791 -18.243,2.305 -14.327,-8.473 -29.747,-14.874 -45.831,-19.025 -6.624,-1.709 -11.252,-7.683 -11.252,-14.524v-22.15c0,-9.447 -7.687,-17.133 -17.134,-17.133h-32.133c-9.447,0 -17.134,7.686 -17.134,17.133v22.148c0,6.841 -4.628,12.815 -11.252,14.524 -16.084,4.151 -31.504,10.552 -45.831,19.025 -5.896,3.485 -13.401,2.537 -18.243,-2.305l-15.688,-15.689c-6.764,-6.772 -17.627,-6.615 -24.224,-0.007l-22.727,22.726c-6.582,6.574 -6.802,17.437 -0.006,24.225l15.695,15.695c4.842,4.842 5.79,12.348 2.305,18.242 -8.473,14.326 -14.873,29.746 -19.024,45.831 -1.71,6.624 -7.684,11.251 -14.524,11.251h-22.148c-9.447,0.001 -17.134,7.687 -17.134,17.134v32.134c0,9.447 7.687,17.133 17.134,17.133h22.147c6.841,0 12.814,4.628 14.524,11.251 4.151,16.085 10.552,31.505 19.024,45.831 3.485,5.894 2.537,13.4 -2.305,18.242l-15.689,15.689c-6.782,6.774 -6.605,17.634 -0.006,24.225l22.725,22.725c6.587,6.596 17.451,6.789 24.225,0.006l15.694,-15.695c3.568,-3.567 10.991,-6.594 18.244,-2.304z" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="m256,367.4c-61.427,0 -111.4,-49.974 -111.4,-111.4s49.973,-111.4 111.4,-111.4 111.4,49.974 111.4,111.4 -49.973,111.4 -111.4,111.4zM256,174.6c-44.885,0 -81.4,36.516 -81.4,81.4s36.516,81.4 81.4,81.4 81.4,-36.516 81.4,-81.4 -36.515,-81.4 -81.4,-81.4z" />
</vector>
```

and the preview of which is as follows

[image]

Vector for android:icon="@drawable/ic_search2"

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:viewportHeight="24" android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="@android:color/white" android:pathData="M15.5,14h-0.79l-0.28,-0.27C15.41,12.59 16,11.11 16,9.5 16,5.91 13.09,3 9.5,3S3,5.91 3,9.5 5.91,16 9.5,16c1.61,0 3.09,-0.59 4.23,-1.57l0.27,0.28v0.79l5,4.99L20.49,19l-4.99,-5zM9.5,14C7.01,14 5,11.99 5,9.5S7.01,5 9.5,5 14,7.01 14,9.5 11.99,14 9.5,14z"/>
</vector>
```

and the preview is

[image]

vector for android:icon="@drawable/ic_reach_us"

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:tint="#145979"
    android:viewportHeight="24" android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="@android:color/white" android:pathData="M21,12.22C21,6.73 16.74,3 12,3c-4.69,0 -9,3.65 -9,9.28C2.4,12.62 2,13.26 2,14v2c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h1v-6.1c0,-3.87 3.13,-7 7,-7s7,3.13 7,7V19h-8v2h8c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2v-1.22c0.59,-0.31 1,-0.92 1,-1.64v-2.3C22,13.14 21.59,12.53 21,12.22z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="@android:color/white" android:pathData="M9,13m-1,0a1,1 0,1 1,2 0a1,1 0,1 1,-2 0"/>
    <path android:fillColor="@android:color/white" android:pathData="M15,13m-1,0a1,1 0,1 1,2 0a1,1 0,1 1,-2 0"/>
    <path android:fillColor="@android:color/white" android:pathData="M18,11.03C17.52,8.18 15.04,6 12.05,6c-3.03,0 -6.29,2.51 -6.03,6.45c2.47,-1.01 4.33,-3.21 4.86,-5.89C12.19,9.19 14.88,11 18,11.03z"/>
</vector>
```

and the preview of it,

[image]

As shown in the first image search icon appears in white in the preview but when I run the app,  only 'action_settings' appears in white colour, whereas the 'my_search_bar' appears in black or some kind of dark colour and help appears as in its preview (the last image). I wanted everything to be white.

As you can see `fillColour` for the search icon and the help icon are white in the vector code. What went wrong with my code?

Edit:

Also, the overflow icon appears in black (or some kind of dark colour). It's not shown in the images I have provided as I replaced `never` with `ifRoom`.

Following is `styles.xml`

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/colorBorder</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


<style name="ProgressBarStyle">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="DemoTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>

    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorOfStatusBar</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

After adding `android:tint="?android:attr/colorForeground"` in the vector icons appeared as in the below image.

[image]

Following is how I have added `android:tint="?android:attr/colorForeground"` in the vector code. The preview of each icon shows black now.

NOTE:: Search icon is NOT BLACK, please check the last image. Settings and Help icons are changed from white to black after making this change whereas the search icon is still the same (Something like a grey colour)

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:tint="?android:attr/colorForeground">
  <path
      android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
      android:pathData="M15.5,14h-0.79l-0.28,-0.27C15.41,12.59 16,11.11 16,9.5 16,5.91 13.09,3 9.5,3S3,5.91 3,9.5 5.91,16 9.5,16c1.61,0 3.09,-0.59 4.23,-1.57l0.27,0.28v0.79l5,4.99L20.49,19l-4.99,-5zM9.5,14C7.01,14 5,11.99 5,9.5S7.01,5 9.5,5 14,7.01 14,9.5 11.99,14 9.5,14z"/>
</vector>
```

Also note,

I have `setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbarHome)` in the `onCreate` of the 'HomeActivity' and following is my `Toolbar`

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/app_gradient_color_background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/colorWhite"/>
```

Comment: You have a tint on the last image.

Comment: android:tint="#145979" edit  this line   android:tint="#FFFFFF" into  ic_reach_us

Comment: @Amitpandey it worked for 'ic_reach_us' and the same value is there in 'ic_search2' but that still appears in black. Note that the overflow icon aslo appears in black/dark colour. Please check my question after the Edit.

Comment: @RogerLindsjö That tint was already removed but I forgot to remove it from my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't explain why the search icon is not white when you run the app, but the help icon clearly is marked to be tinted blue (`android:tint="#145979"`). `android:tint` in the parent `vector` element overrides the color of any child `path` elements.

I suggest you set `android:tint="?android:attr/colorForeground"` in the top level `vector` element of all of these so they can follow your theming. Then if you decide to make them a different color or have a day/night theme where they are a different color during the day, you only have to change it in the theme in one spot, and they will always match the overflow icon color.

If you want white text and icons on your action bar, I suggest you use a parent theme that has `DarkActionBar` in its name, or if you are using `NoActionBar` and including a Toolbar in your layout that you set as the support action bar, then set an `actionBarTheme` with a DarkActionBar parent, such as including:

```xml
<item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar</item>
```

This will make the overflow icon white as well.

---

Edit: I realized the above only works if you use a theme with a window decor action bar instead of a NoActionBar theme with a Toolbar in the layout.

The help icon needed its tint changed to white in the XML.

From the comments: The search button was getting externally tinted because of it having `actionViewClass` in the menu XML. It was using `colorOnPrimary` from the theme to tint its icon. So instead of just using `@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar` as the `actionBarTheme`, you had to create a custom action bar overlay theme and use that.

```xml
<style name="MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
     <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>     
</style>

<!-- and inside the app theme: -->
<item name="actionBarTheme">@style/MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar</item>
```

Comment: I have added my `styles.xml` in the question, can you take a look?

Comment: I added `<item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar</item>` in line of code inside `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">`. Still the overflow and search icons are not white. Is there any other changes I have to make. I have updated latest `styles.xml` in my question.

Comment: No, I have updated the result in the question. I have also included some more details about the `Toolbar`.

Comment: By the way, did you set a `app:navigationIcon` element in your MaterialToolbar element in your layout? I discovered a bug that if you set this icon to the same drawable as one of your menu items, then the menu item gets tinted by the `navigationIconTint` property in the theme, overriding whatever is in the drawable code. So for example if you have `app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_search2"` in your MaterialToolbar, your icon will be tinted improperly.

Comment: I tried adding `android:tint="@color/appBarIconTint"` and defining the colour in your resources to be `#ffffff` but that didn't work. I don't have `app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_search2"` in my toolbar `xml`. I have added `xml` code of the toolbar in the question. can you check?

Comment: No, that didn't work.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying, actually I was trying some experiments so I thought I would add that too in the comment. Since it was taking the time I replied to you just that.  I know you have tried your best to help me out, but I don't think you are really out of ideas or can't find a solution to this. Anyways I will let you know my new findings on this in a moment. thanks

Comment: I added one more item in my `home_menu.xml` and used the same icon (android:icon="@drawable/ic_search2") and it appeared white. and noticed that the colour changes to the grey when I add `app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"` to it.

Comment: However, this did not resolve my issue, as you know the search won't work without it. I was just trying to find what is causing the issue.

Comment: Sounds similar to the bug I found mentioned above. In the case of that bug, I saw it was absorbing the color for `navigationIconTint` in the theme. If you can figure out which color it's absorbing for an `actionViewClass` you could set that value in your action bar theme.

Comment: The issue is now fixed :). Thanks for your time and effort. After adding `android:theme="@style/MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar"` to `<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar` and `<style name="MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
    </style>`. Please include this in your answer so that I can mark that as the accepted answer. There is one more issue though and I would highly appreciate if you can tell me a way to fix that, maybe programmatically. The search text is not white still :(.

Comment: I accomplished that with `val searchView = item?.actionView as SearchView
        val searchEditText = searchView.findViewById<EditText>(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)
        searchEditText.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.colorWhite))`

Comment: The solution for me was adding ```android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal"``` to the icon.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

For the search icon, try changing

`android:tint="#FFFFFF"`

to

`android:tint="#FFFFFFFF"`

I don't *believe* there is a default alpha (like there is in HTML), so your tint color is white, but has zero alpha.

Comment: it didn't work.